while (true) loop executing once more after break statement when reading file
I'm trying to read a file that has this format:
1
2
3
4

I'm trying to store these values into an array using a while loop:
ifstream myfile("file.dat");
int n, i;
int myarray[30];

if (!myfile) {cerr << "File not Found!" << endl;}

i = 0;
while (true) {

  if (myfile.eof()) {break;}
  myfile >> n;
  myarray[i] = n;
  cout << myarray[i] << endl;
  i++;
}

When I execute the program, the result from cout is
1
2
3
4
4

It seems like the program is executing the last iteration of the while loop a second time. But why? I have a break statement in it that should exit out of the loop once end of file is reached. Is the break statement not appropriate for this?

Relevant: Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong.

The C++ variant of the one mentioned above might be more relevant.

@Someprogrammerdude you are right. Although I believe the root cause is similar.

TL;DR of the dupe.  if (myfile.eof()) {break;} wont trigger until the stream actually reads the EOF, which is one more iteration after you read the last value.

Later versions of C++ guarantee that myfile >> n; when EOF will result in n being default initialized, rather than either uninitialized or the (stale) previous value.
